# v$ or rc views to report on RMAN restore database preview

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, rman, disaster-recovery

Setup:

We take an Incremental level 0 backup weekly using:

```
RMAN> backup as compressed backupset incremental level 0 database;
RMAN> backup check logical as compressed backupset (archivelog all delete all input);
```

We take an Incremental level 1 backup nightly (except on the night that we take the incremental level 0 backup) using:

```
RMAN> backup as compressed backupset incremental level 1 database;
RMAN> backup check logical as compressed backupset (archivelog all delete all input);
```

In RMAN, I know that I can report on when recovery will start and which SCN will need to be restored in order to clear the datafile fuzziness to bring the database to a consistent state using the following:

```
RMAN> restore database preview;

Media recovery start SCN is 49928711194
Recovery must be done beyond SCN 49928711196 to clear datafile fuzziness
```

This tells me that if I issue a `restore database;` i'll need to recover SCN's 49928711194 to 49928711196 before I can open the database.

From here, I know that I can query which archivelog backups are available and which SCNs these archivelog backups contain using:

```
SELECT sequence#, first_change#, next_change#, id2, handle from (
  SELECT sequence#, first_change#, next_change#, id2
    FROM v$backup_archivelog_details where 49928711194 between first_change# and next_change#
UNION
  SELECT sequence#, first_change#, next_change#, id2
    FROM v$backup_archivelog_details where 49928711196 between first_change# and next_change#) archivelog
  JOIN v$backup_piece p
    ON archivelog.id2=p.set_count;

SEQUENCE#   FIRST_CHANGE#   NEXT_CHANGE#    ID2     HANDLE
22030       49923438913     49928711521     7940    L:\ORACLE\BACKUPS\ARCH_2_7940_1
```

My question is: is there a way to query a `v$` view or `rc` view to obtain the start SCN and beyond SCN that `RMAN> restore database preview;` provides in order to clear the datafile fuzziness for a given backupset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> #### V$BACKUP_DATAFILE
>
> V$BACKUP_DATAFILE displays information about control files and datafiles in backup sets from the control file.

```
Media recovery start SCN is 7962109213
Recovery must be done beyond SCN 7962156379 to clear datafile fuzziness 
Finished restore at 28-JUN-2017 09:27:17
```

And what I am interested in is `ABSOLUTE_FUZZY_CHANGE#` and `CHECKPOINT_CHANGE#`  column of that view.

> `CHECKPOINT_CHANGE#`: All changes up to the checkpoint change number are included in this backup
>
> `ABSOLUTE_FUZZY_CHANGE#`:  Highest change number in this backup

I used the following query to get the same result as given by RMAN restore preview command.

```
SQL>   select max(absolute_fuzzy_change#) fuzz#, max(checkpoint_change#) chkpnt# from
                        (select file#, completion_time, checkpoint_change#, absolute_fuzzy_change# from v$backup_datafile
                        where  trunc(completion_time) = to_date('JUN-28-2017','MON-DD-YYYY')
                        and file# <> 0
                        order by completion_time desc
                        ); 

     FUZZ#    CHKPNT#
---------- ----------
7962156379 7962109213
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I briefly looked over all of the v$backup views including v$backup_datafile, but must have missed the checkpoint_change# and absolute_fuzzy_change# columns.